# How to find the clang::SourceRange of a deleted function?

Tags: c++, clang, abstract-syntax-tree, libtooling, clang-ast-matchers

I am working on a Clang AST generated from the following source code:

```
struct has_deleted_function_member
{
void deleted_function1() = delete;
//~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^ col:33
};

void deleted_function2() = delete;
//~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^ col:24

int main()
{
  return 0;
}
```

I would like to find the complete `SourceRange` of the `FunctionDecl`s of `has_deleted_function_member::deleted_function1` and `deleted_function2`.

By complete, I mean that I would like these `SourceRange`s to include the complete declarations of these functions, beginning with and including the leading `void` and up to and excluding the trailing semicolon.

Calling `getSourceRange` on `deleted_function1`'s `FunctionDecl` yields the desired result as expected.

However, `getSourceRange` on `deleted_function2`'s `FunctionDecl` ends at its closing right paren.

The AST dump of these functions:

```
CXXMethodDecl 0x1299b40 <line:3:1, col:33> col:6 deleted_function1 'void ()' delete
FunctionDecl 0x1299c38 <line:7:1, col:24> col:6 deleted_function2 'void ()' delete
```

Is the exclusion of `deleted_function2`'s trailing `= delete` a bug, or is this the intended behavior?

If it is not a bug, is it possible to programmatically find the complete `SourceRange` of `deleted_function2`?

Compiler details:

```
❯ clang++ --version
Ubuntu clang version 14.0.0-1ubuntu1.1
Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /usr/bin
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm reasonably confident this is a bug.  The desired location isn't
available as far as I can tell.  Moreover, I think I see where the bug
is.

In
[`clang/lib/Parse/ParseCXXInlineMethods.cpp`](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/llvmorg-16.0.6/clang/lib/Parse/ParseCXXInlineMethods.cpp#L66),
we have:

```
NamedDecl *Parser::ParseCXXInlineMethodDef(
  [...]
  if (TryConsumeToken(tok::equal)) {
    [...]
    if (TryConsumeToken(tok::kw_delete, KWLoc)) {
      Diag(KWLoc, getLangOpts().CPlusPlus11
                      ? diag::warn_cxx98_compat_defaulted_deleted_function
                      : diag::ext_defaulted_deleted_function)
        << 1 /* deleted */;
      Actions.SetDeclDeleted(FnD, KWLoc);
      Delete = true;
      if (auto *DeclAsFunction = dyn_cast<FunctionDecl>(FnD)) {
        DeclAsFunction->setRangeEnd(KWEndLoc);                  <============
      }
    } else if (TryConsumeToken(tok::kw_default, KWLoc)) {
      Diag(KWLoc, getLangOpts().CPlusPlus11
                      ? diag::warn_cxx98_compat_defaulted_deleted_function
                      : diag::ext_defaulted_deleted_function)
        << 0 /* defaulted */;
      Actions.SetDeclDefaulted(FnD, KWLoc);
      if (auto *DeclAsFunction = dyn_cast<FunctionDecl>(FnD)) {
        DeclAsFunction->setRangeEnd(KWEndLoc);
      }
    } else {
      llvm_unreachable("function definition after = not 'delete' or 'default'");
    }
```

but in
[`clang/lib/Parse/Parser.cpp`](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/llvmorg-16.0.6/clang/lib/Parse/Parser.cpp#L1365),
we have what looks like a partial copy+paste:

```
Decl *Parser::ParseFunctionDefinition(ParsingDeclarator &D,
  [...]
  if (TryConsumeToken(tok::equal)) {
    assert(getLangOpts().CPlusPlus && "Only C++ function definitions have '='");

    if (TryConsumeToken(tok::kw_delete, KWLoc)) {
      Diag(KWLoc, getLangOpts().CPlusPlus11
                      ? diag::warn_cxx98_compat_defaulted_deleted_function
                      : diag::ext_defaulted_deleted_function)
          << 1 /* deleted */;
      BodyKind = Sema::FnBodyKind::Delete;
    } else if (TryConsumeToken(tok::kw_default, KWLoc)) {
      Diag(KWLoc, getLangOpts().CPlusPlus11
                      ? diag::warn_cxx98_compat_defaulted_deleted_function
                      : diag::ext_defaulted_deleted_function)
          << 0 /* defaulted */;
      BodyKind = Sema::FnBodyKind::Default;
    } else {
      llvm_unreachable("function definition after = not 'delete' or 'default'");
    }
```

The above is missing the `setRangeEnd` call that the first block has.

I confirmed that adding the required updates fixes the bug, and filed this as [Issue 64805](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues/64805).

### Possible workaround: ad-hoc text search

In cases where the clang `SourceLocation` information is missing or
inadequate, I've gotten reasonably good results by getting the raw
source from
[`SourceManager`](https://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1SourceManager.html)
`::getBufferData`, turn `SourceLocation`s into byte offsets with
the `SourceManager::getFileOffset` method, and do ad-hoc text searches.
You could do something like that to recognize and skip the `=delete`
in this case.

Obviously it's not foolproof, since macros will mess things up, and
dealing with comments and preprocessor directives is annoying, but the
clang `SourceLocation` also has some issues with macros when doing
source-to-source transformations so it's not like driving off a fidelity
cliff.

I'll also note that I have *not* had much luck trying to use the
[`Lexer`](https://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1Lexer.html) class
for this sort of thing, although it's of course possible I don't know
how to use it properly.

Update: OP has provided a [nice example](https://gist.github.com/jaredhoberock/c904f36096dc02498507ad010ffe3f5d) of using `Lexer` to work around this problem.  I stand corrected!

Comment: Thanks for confirming this likely bug. In the meantime, I've had some success lexxing for the `delete` with code like this: https://gist.github.com/jaredhoberock/c904f36096dc02498507ad010ffe3f5d